# Returning sprite from coroutine

Tags: c#, image, unity-game-engine, ienumerator

I currently have 2 functions.

My first one is an `IEnumerator`, let's call it `LoadImage`, it handles downloading the image from a URL.

```
IEnumerator LoadImage()
{
    WWW www = new WWW("https://s3-ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com/myeyehouse/uimg/scimg/sc661120171130095837184/pano/thumb_Eyehouse.jpg");
    while (!www.isDone)
    {
        Debug.Log("Download image on progress" + www.progress);
        yield return null;
    }

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(www.error))
    {
        Debug.Log("Download failed");
    }
    else
    {
        Debug.Log("Download succes");
        Texture2D texture = new Texture2D(1, 1);
        www.LoadImageIntoTexture(texture);

        Sprite sprite = Sprite.Create(texture,
            new Rect(0, 0, texture.width, texture.height), Vector2.zero);
        return sprite;

    }
}
```

My second function needs to assign that `LoadImage()`'s output (which is a sprite) to my `GameObject`. I cant just put my `GameObject` and load it in the `LoadImage()` function. If possible, I need advice on how I can assign my the sprite from the `LoadImage()` function.

Comment: Why are you returning IEnumerator?  That's going to  give you a set of 0 or more nulls followed by 0 or 1 sprites.  Why not just return the `Sprite` or `null` if it fails?

Comment: @juharr ah yes that is what I mean. as seen from my code, i have a 'yield return sprite;' line. how can i call that to my second function?

Comment: `yield return null;` is likely to be a bug. Also, don't use the non-generic `IEnumerator`. Always use `IEnumerator<T>`, or a deriving type and you will understand what @juharr is getting at.

Comment: You do realize that unity now supports `async` - `await`? You seem to want an asynchronous method, use the best [tools available](http://www.stevevermeulen.com/index.php/2017/09/using-async-await-in-unity3d-2017/).

Comment: @juharr Iterators are a way to implement asynchronous methods in Unity which didn't support `async`-`await` until very recently. The method is a mess though.

Answer (score 2):

You can't return a value from coroutine. So you need to use delegate.
I would return the Texture and leave the Sprite creation out.

```
IEnumerator LoadImage(Action<Texture2D> callback)
{
    WWW www = new WWW("https://s3-ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com/myeyehouse/uimg/scimg/sc661120171130095837184/pano/thumb_Eyehouse.jpg");
    while (!www.isDone)
    {
        Debug.Log("Download image on progress" + www.progress);
        yield return null;
    }

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(www.error))
    {
        Debug.Log("Download failed");
        callback(null);
    }
    else
    {
        Debug.Log("Download succes");
        Texture2D texture = new Texture2D(1, 1);
        www.LoadImageIntoTexture(texture);
        callback(texture);
    }
}
```

Then you call:

```
void Start()
{
    StartCoroutine(LoadImage(CreateSpriteFromTexture));
}
private CreateSpriteFromTexture(Texture2D texture)
{
        if(texture == null) { return;}
        Sprite sprite = Sprite.Create(texture,
            new Rect(0, 0, texture.width, texture.height), Vector2.zero);
        // Assign sprite to image
}
```

The whole challenge is to understand how delegate and action work.