# Is it possible to return the result of an UnityWebRequest from Coroutine method?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, coroutine, unitywebrequest

I'm trying to return the result of an UnityWebRequest request from a coroutined method, I thought about something like the following code:

```
    private IEnumerator<string> SendPostWebRequest(string url)
    {
        WWWForm form = new WWWForm();
        form.AddField("Key", "Value");

        using (UnityWebRequest request = UnityWebRequest.Post(url, form))
        {
            yield return request.SendWebRequest();

            if (!request.isNetworkError && !request.isHttpError && request.isDone)
                yield return request.downloadHandler.text;

            yield return string.Empty;
        }
    }
```

But there is an error in this line (yield return request.SendWebRequest()) and I can't figure out how to fix it! (a yield here is required to wait the completion of the request).

Comment: And what is the error you're getting exactly?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47805381/returning-sprite-from-coroutine change the sprite for a string

Comment: @hololady The error is something like "the return type should be a string..."

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Returning sprite from coroutine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47805381/returning-sprite-from-coroutine)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30267537/unity-need-to-return-value-only-after-coroutine-finishes check this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see that this function return type is IEnumerator, and notice that the 'request.SendWebRequest();' return a Task. So the first thing to fix this issue would be removing the generic type , leave it just like:

```
private IEnumerator<string> SendPostWebRequest(){....}
```

Of the other hand, you need to return a string. According to Unity's documentation the following code should work for cases that the function is not a Coroutine:

```
string str = (string) SendPostWebRequest(...);
```

This will cast all elements yielded in the IEnumerator and will return the first string element on it.

However, this is a Coroutine, and from my experience this does not work. The solutions that I figured out and I usually use is the use of a lambda function.

To approach this you need to add an extra argument to your function, an Action (basically functions references) so you can execute it from your SendPostWebRequest() function. I sounds confusing but take a look at this code. This is how I usually implement this kind of things.

```
public void ExampleFunction(){
    // Using lambda function
    StartCoroutine(SendPostWebRequest("www.google.es", (string ReturnResult)=> 
           Debug.Log(ReturnResult)
    ));

    // Using functions references
    StartCoroutine(SendPostWebRequest("www.google.es", OtherResultManagementFunction));
}

private void OtherResultManagementFunction(string ReturnResult){
    Debug.Log(ReturnResult);
}

private IEnumerator SendPostWebRequest(string url, Action<string> FinishDelegate)
    {
        WWWForm form = new WWWForm();
        form.AddField("Key", "Value");

        using (UnityWebRequest request = UnityWebRequest.Post(url, form))
        {
            yield return request.SendWebRequest();

            if (!request.isNetworkError && !request.isHttpError && request.isDone)
                yield return request.downloadHandler.text;

            FinishDelegate("WHATEVER STRING");
        }
    }
```

The generic Action specifies the return time of the function encapsulated in the Action object.

Both coroutines works exactly in the same way, but the first uses a lambda fucntion and the other a function reference. If executed, both would print the string returned from the webrequest (in this case "WHATEVER STRING").

Hope this works for you, It is the best solution for me in most cases.

Comment: Thanks @adri-ollero,  I know this solution but I'm trying to find a simpler one without the delegate :)
BTW I suggest this change to your code:
`if (!request.isNetworkError && !request.isHttpError && request.isDone)
                FinishDelegate?.Invoke(request.downloadHandler.text);`